# Failed to define the target at build.zig

Tags: zig

I'm at linux and want to cross compile for windows, I've the below that is working file for building the executable at linux:

```
pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {

    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});

    // const target = "x86_64-windows";


    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const exe = b.addExecutable("Zig", "src/main.zig");
    exe.setTarget(target);
    exe.setBuildMode(mode);
    exe.install();
}
```

I tried to use `const target = "x86_64-windows";` but it failed telling that `error: expected type 'zig.CrossTarget', found '*const [14:0]u8'`

Comment: Why not just use the `-Dtarget=` option when invoking `zig build`?

Comment: @adabsurdum I want to learn and understand both approached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass a `CrossTarget`.

```js
const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };
```

also as @ad-absurdum said you can just run `zig build -Dtarget=x86_64-windows`